# How move object horizontal in android with example

Tags: android

I am new to android.I am developing the game it is a shooting game so i need a gun to move on the screen and hunt animals.Now i need gun moving horizontally can any one help me please..
how can i move a object on the screen.

Comment: can any tell me how to move a object

Comment: We all can solve your problem,but can't go on to work for you completely!! :))

Comment: ok thanks sir thanks for your valuable suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Check this [Blog](http://obviam.net/index.php/moving-images-on-the-screen-with-androi/). I had also created a shooting game with the help of this blog.

This shows how an image can be moved on screen. The source code for the same is available in the blog itself.

In the beginning of the tutorial itself they have given a link to there previos article, I would suggest you read the previous article first as the later articles are extension of the previous ones. Reading from the first article will help understanding the concept better.

Please feel free to ask if you face any issues

Comment: simple code i am unable to understand that code i have seen it before asking in stack overflow i couldn't understand please help me i need to move gun in horizontal motion

Comment: Read from the first article where they explain how to display image first.

Comment: @SANJEEVREDDY In that code they are moving the droid when there is touch and drag to move in horizontal direction, just change the x axis value of your image in the `onDraw()` of the program.